# Building model from different types of features using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I am using 3 types of feature classes (Point,Line and Poly).

Now I want to give some common field and name those features.

How do I build the model using ArcMap 10.1?

Answer (score 3):

The decision making logic is based on a simple script:

```
import sys, arcpy

desc = arcpy.Describe(sys.argv[1])
if desc.shapeType == "Polygon":
    arcpy.SetParameter(1,True)
    arcpy.SetParameter(2,False)
    arcpy.SetParameter(3,False)
elif desc.shapeType == "Polyline":
    arcpy.SetParameter(1,False)
    arcpy.SetParameter(2,True)
    arcpy.SetParameter(3,False)
elif desc.shapeType == "Point":
    arcpy.SetParameter(1,False)
    arcpy.SetParameter(2,False)
    arcpy.SetParameter(3,True)
else:
    # must be multipoint or multipatch
    arcpy.SetParameter(1,False)
    arcpy.SetParameter(2,False)
    arcpy.SetParameter(3,False)# none of these will execute
```

[image]

Then use it in a model like this:
[image]

Each of the output is a precondition for a branch, only one of the 3 will execute. To bring the branches back together use [Merge Branch](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004000000007000000.htm) when you're finished with the polygon/line/point difference.

To use this script in a model:

1. Copy the script and paste into Notepad (or your favorite text editor)
2. Save the script as file type .py; you will need to [turn on extensions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7) if using notepad to ensure that the file is not saved as .py.txt.
3. Create a toolbox in ArcCatalog - right click in a folder and select new>Toolbox
4. Right click on the toolbox and select add>Script ([full details are here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000001r000000)), be sure to follow the image called `Add Script` or it will not work properly.
5. Drag the tool from the toolbox into your model.
6. Connect the input feature class to your process (see image from model builder).
7. Use the outputs (Point, Polygon, Line) as [preconditions](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000007r000000) to your branches. Only one of the preconditions will be satisfied by any input so two of the three will not execute.